# passing a list as an argument in TCL

Tags: tcl

I tried create a procedure that gets a list from the user and prints the min and max values of the list.
I think that the problem is passing the list as an argument to the procedure.
Here is my code:

```
proc minmaxlist {mylist} {
    lsort -integer $mylist
    puts "my list is: $mylist\n"
    #puts "the length is $argc\n"
    set min [lindex $mylist 0]
    set max [lindex $mylist [llength[mylist] -1]]
    puts "max is $max"
    puts "min is $min"
}

set mylist [list $argv]

minmaxlist $mylist
```

I found that if my list is {5 7 0} my list[0] gets the value of  5 7 0 instead of 5. 
Thanks!

Comment: `argv` is already a list, so you're putting that list into a new list: `mylist` will have only a single element. Try `minmaxlist $argv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not passing the list to the procedure, but the `[list $argv]`. The argv variable already contains a list. By wrapping it in another list command, you end up with a list with only one element (which itself is another list). That single element will then end up to be both the minimum and maximum value. So, just pass $argv to the proc, or set mylist to $argv, instead of [list $argv].

Then in your proc, you sort the list and discard the result. You will want to store the result in a variable. You can reuse mylist for that: `set mylist [lsort -integer $mylist]`.

You may also have noticed that your statement to get the max value doesn't work. You probably meant to do `set max [lindex $mylist [expr {[llength $mylist] - 1}]]`. The last element can more easily be obtained via `set max [lindex $mylist end]`